# I found out about this site on Facebook... or "at Facebook"?

Tags: prepositions

Would this look natural:

> StackExchange is a helluva site! I found out about this site **at** Facebook.

Or should we use the preposition **on**:

> StackExchange is a helluva site! I found out about this site **on** Facebook.

Or are both okay?

(Inspired by a [lang-8 post](http://lang-8.com/1290042/journals/105053066340181359199061865053689775150))

Comment: "on"  wins for  frequency, but "at" is not wrong.  To be ornery, you can say "in|on the Facebook".

Comment: ornery? "ugly and unpleasant in disposition or temper"? You probably meant to say "ornate" (0:

Comment: [**ornery**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ornery): 2. obstinate. To me it is like not automatically agreeing with something.

Comment: I think most people would use *on*. Using *at* makes it seem like a physical location. "Clouds" don't qualify.

Comment: Yeah, *at* seems to indicate an unusual conceptualization of Facebook as a location.

Comment: Oh, I'd like to add one more comment: If you worked at Facebook (or used to work at Facebook) and found out about Stack Exchange in the course of your employment, then it would make sense to say you found out about it *at* Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that discussion works about the internet is different from the way that discussion works about other things.

For an actual physical location, you would use "at":

> I found out about the concert at my friend's house.

or

> She met him at Talbothays Dairy Farm.

However, when refering to websites by their name(at least in this context), you use "on":

> I found the information on wikipedia.

You *would* use "at," though, if you were talking about an actual website address, or link:

> You can find the information at www.wikipedia.com/help.

Comment: Can we consider 'in' also? How would be: you are _in Stack.exchange_ or _on Stack.exchange_ ?

Comment: @Isa No, we don't use 'in' in this context.

Comment: @OldBrixtonian Thank you.