# Do you write posts "on", "for", or "in" social media groups?

Tags: prepositions

Do you write posts "on", "for", or "in" social media groups? For example, you could set up a rock band and publish updates on your Facebook page about your new albums and the like

Comment: Here is a nice answer about **at** vs **on**: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61442/i-found-out-about-this-site-on-facebook-or-at-facebook

Comment: You'd usually publish a post on a site, not on a group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case of using "group", the preposition "on/in" are both viable. But we usually do not *post on/in a group*, it is *post on a site*.

Comment: You could easily post *on* a site, *in* a group, *to* your fans.